# Do we have any lib to capture the state changes using sagas?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Basically need to build a warning modal , when user tries to move from current page/screen to another page , showing there are some saved changes .

Any implementations using redux and redux saga

Answer (score 0):

Sagas *are* the lib for this - they watch for any action of a specified type. Navigation will take two actions: one to indicate that navigation is about to happen (which the saga will watch) and one to actually update the current page. The saga watches for actions of the first type and shows a warning dialog if the data has changed.

Ex:

```
function showWarning(action) {
  if (/* data has been changed but not saved */) {
    displayWarningDialog(action.pageToNavigateTo)
  }
  else {
    // action that updates the page/location
    completeNavigation(action.pageToNavigateTo)
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
  // NAVIGATE_TO_PAGE_X are the actions that get fired when a user changes pages
  yield takeEvery("NAVIGATE_TO_PAGE_1", showWarning)
  yield takeEvery("NAVIGATE_TO_PAGE_2", showWarning)
}
```

Comment: But mainly how to capture state changes in redux ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the amazing [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) for state debugging. This tool was built by Redux author himself.

Here  are its features

- Lets you inspect every state and action payload
- Lets you go back in time by “cancelling” actions
- If you change the reducer code, each “staged” action will be
  re-evaluated
- If the reducers throw, you will see during which action this
  happened, and what the error was
- With persistState() store enhancer, you can persist debug sessions
  across page reloads

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about this recently as well and been thinking about writing some form of middleware to intercept routing actions.

When intercepting a routing action, the middleware could determine if application state indicates the user is editing some unsaved data, and if so, dispatch a different action instead. That action should reduce state and cause a warning to render. The user could then confirm wanting to continue navigating by dispatching an action also intercepted by the middleware to continue the routing process.